# ASP.Net: Users are logged out when deploying a new file to the server

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, iis, application-pool

Everytime I upload a file to my ASP.NET site, all users are logged out (aka, I guess their session become invalidated).

Is there any way to "hotswap" the code in ASP.NET so that this doesn't happen? Compile before deploying etc.

My deployment method is pretty simple through a SVN update.

Thanks!
/Niels

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could store your session in a [SQL database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229862(VS.80).aspx), thus the application restart would not lose your sessions.

Having precompiled non updatable code to deploy would make your xcopy faster alright but app pool would still be restarted.

UPDATE: @configurator, making your comment visible to any casual observers
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317604

(there is plenty of coverage of the different options and how-tos out there, e.g. more than one session db, different frameworks dbs in same db, etc)

Comment: This sounds like a solution that I'd like to approach. Could you elaborate?

Comment: You don't need to go for the SQL database approach, you can use the ASP.NET state service to accomplish the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

If you're deploying files to the bin folder or the web.config, this will automatically reset the site for very good reasons.